# A simple MySQL update query takes ages. Indexing problem?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE ps_product_check SET `google_shopping_link`= '777' WHERE `google_shopping_link`= '778'
```

> 635 rows affected. (Query took 452.8805 seconds.)

The table has 55000 rows, 39 columns. There are some indexes, one of which is featuring the column name in question.

There are lot of tutorials on HOW to create the indexes technically but couldn't find any which do explain the logic behind it.

This particular query used to take a fraction to complete, now it is 8 minutes.

Is it indexing, or could it be something else? Any reply is valued, can provide more data if needed.

Comment: It's indexing, but those inverted commas don't help

Comment: 635 rows affected. (Query took 0.0351 seconds.)
Thank you, really saved the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index lead the query to work only on the subset of table rows  really matching the query oeration  so

You have  where condition on google_shopping_link column then  proper index is based on this column  ..

be sure you have a index  o

```
table  ps_product_check column google_shopping_link
```

Answer (score 1):

An index on the `google_shopping_link` field would help.

As for the logic of how to use indexes, there are whole books on that topic.